# Reportviewer Report Filter - Check Date If Null

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm working in a c# windows application with vs2010 and a local database.In one of my forms i use a ReporViewer to display a report.

I would like to be able to show results from a record in this report only if a specific field (witch is a date) is not null.
I created a table and i added a filter but seems that the expression i use is wrong.

I used something like this, in the **Tablix Properties** - Filters:

expression   `=IsNothing(Fields!payed.Value)`

operator     `=`

value        `=true`

Any ideas?Thanks in advance!
Maybe i forgot the = in the value input. It's working now!

Comment: Are you trying to hide the Tablix if the specific date is null?

Comment: No, Just not to show any results. Meaning that if date is not null then show some fields of this specific record

Comment: I just want to create a Filter that checks If a Field (which is a date) is null!

Comment: What is the expression you are using for ReportViewer filter?

Comment: The expression is shown in my question. It is created throuth the Filter "guide"

Comment: My mistake, it's working as it is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

expression `=IsNothing(Fields!payed.Value)`

operator `=`

value `= true`

where payed is a date field

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!payed.Value),"Show_your_desired_value",Fields!payed.Value)
```

the date field should be checked in IsNothing() function. I am asking a question here, is payed is a date variable or not?

Comment: Yes, the payed Field is a Date

Comment: the problem is that in the Tablix Properties -> Filters , it doesn't let me to just declare an expression. I must also declare an operator and a value as shown in my question.This is why i'm having a difficulty with this.Is there an other way around it?

Comment: actually..my question is my answer!! Maybe I forgot an equal sign or something. I tried it again and it is working! Thanks anyway